# NSUserNotification presented delegate?

Tags: cocoa, notifications

Is there some callback when a NSUserNotification disappears after timeout?

Something like Growl's delegate method 
`- (void) growlNotificationTimedOut:(id)clickContext;`.

I want to use this callback to remove some stored data, which are used if user clicks on the notification.

Thanks!

Comment: If your stored data is small enough (less than 1K) you could consider storing it in the NSUserNotification `userInfo` property so it's removed automatically if the notification is removed.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a roundabout way to do it, but your  `NSUserNotification` has a `presented` property that lets you know if it was actually shown. You might use this (or just a timer after the notification is delivered) to wait until the notification goes away.

Once you know the notification is gone, you can check the `activationType` property to see how the user interacted with it. If they didn't touch it, do whatever memory removal you need.

Check [Mac Developer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.